# Вычисление чётного факториала

Tags: javascript, html, алгоритм, функции

Не понимаю, почему выскакивает ошибка и как с ней справиться. Пример вычисления факториала `6!! = 6*4*2*1 = 48`

```js
    function doubleFactorial(n) {
        return (n !== 1) ? n * doubleFactorial(n - 2) : 1;
    }
    console.log(doubleFactorial(6));
    console.log(doubleFactorial(7));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function doubleFactorial(n) {
  return (n > 1) ? n * doubleFactorial(n - 2) : 1;
}
console.log(doubleFactorial(6));
console.log(doubleFactorial(7));
```